# Nested SOQL Query in a Flow

Tags: soql, flow, governorlimits

I'm having a hard time designing a flow according to Salesforce best practices, which is of course essentially to limit the number of times you have to interact with the database.  So where I'm having a hard time is trying to replicate the idea of a nested soql query.  I don't see any way to accomplish this, and the only workarounds I can think of involve a lookup within a loop.

I've read that you can write an apex plugin that helps to accomplish this, and it doesn't sound like it would be impossible (even for a non-programmer), but I was really hoping to avoid apex altogether if possible.  Does anyone know of anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what you're doing, and load your SOQL query for us to take a look at?  Perhaps the query itself can be optimized to resolve the issue.

Comment: Specifically I'd like to look up Account Team Member records whose AccountId is in an Account sObject Collection.  I think this is easy in one SOQL statement, but I'm trying to do this as a Visual Workflow, which only gives you limited tools to query the database.  So I can easily look up Account Team Member records whose AccountId is something specific, but I can't figure out how to look them up based on a collection of accounts.