# How to do Nested Query In a Flow

Tags: soql, visual-workflow

There is already a related question [Nested SOQL Query in a Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65746/nested-soql-query-in-a-flow). However it is unanswered and out of date, from more than 7 years ago.

With all of the new capabilities of flows, I want to know if there is any way of doing something like `SELECT Id, (Select FirstName FROM Contacts) FROM Account`, like an inner query or nesed SOQL, with the `Get Records` element of a flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Loop element in the flow to loop through all Contacts in the account, get the Firts Name, store all first names in a variable.
Here is more about loops:
[https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-flow-loops-best-practices-and-examples/#:~:text=A%20Loop%20is%20a%20Salesforce%20Flow%20element%20that,which%20you%20want%20to%20either%20assess%20or%20action](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-flow-loops-best-practices-and-examples/#:%7E:text=A%20Loop%20is%20a%20Salesforce%20Flow%20element%20that,which%20you%20want%20to%20either%20assess%20or%20action).

Answer (score 0):

There is not something out of the box that will make this a clean implementation. I would not suggest a query within a loop as you will hit the SOQL limit fairly question.

You can do 2 separate queries and then loop through each one to create a new collection of the data that you need.

Here is a custom component made by UnofficialSF that seems to solve the problem you are encountering: https://unofficialsf.com/automate-junction-updates-with-getchildcollection-and-getlookupcollection/

Answer (score 0):

The answer has changed now you can use the IN query within Get elements what you can do is loop a add all of account IDs to a collection of account Ids
[image]

To then get only the contacts related to a specific account you can then use the filter element to grab that.